# GCP Load balancing: connecting an URL Map as routing rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, gcp-load-balancer

I recently created a load balancer on GCP which works as intended. I would like now to save the routing rules I created into a .yaml file in a repository and deploy any changes using the CLI.

I created my routing rules using the "advanced" section, and I provided hosts as text and URL matchers as a YAML file.

[image: Load balancer routing rule]

While searching for ways to do what I want, I read a lot about [URL Maps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map) which seem to answer my need : specifying host matchers, path matchers, and even tests !
I browse a lot of documentation pages and I could not see anywhere where I can link an URL Map to my load balancer.

More surprising, it seems that the "Routing Rules" section when I edit the loadbalancer is itself implementing an URL Map, but I cannot access the actual code behind it.

Two examples to illustrate :

1 - I can setup tests from the "simple host and path rule" view, but not in the "advanced" view

[image: Simple configuration]

2 - The description says "you can also submit a custom YAML routing config" but the only thing I can do is setting the path matchers as YAML, not even the host matchers...

Has somebody managed to do this via CLI? Not using terraform. Thank you!

Comment: This link provides documentation and an example: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#example_url_map_workflow_with_an

Comment: @JohnHanley So close and yet so far... Thank you for the link, I was able to follow the steps and it worked. One thing though, I was very surprised to see after importing a configuration that load balancer and URL map are 2 words for the same thing! I find it so ambiguous, and I had to see from my eyes that importing a configuration created another load balancer to understand this...